# how to add only minutes in HH:MM format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting time HH:MM format using

```
dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' })
```

I need to add only minutes?

I am getting one more error this is my date (2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z) here, when I try to display time it displays different time '11:38' I need '06:08'..

```
console.log('data as ', obj);

var dat = obj.starttime; 
let dt = new Date(dat);
console.log('time from database' , dt);
console.log('getMinutes():'  +  dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' })   );

  output of the console.log

   data as  { id: 4009,mid: 1,cid: 41,wid: 7138,oid: null,
  status: null,options: null, starttime: '2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z',
  duration: null,ordertotal: 50,counter: null,closetime: null } 

   time from database 2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z
   getMinutes():11:38 AM
```

Here I am getting different time than required time...and I need to add only minutes to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `timeZone` option and to add minutes use [Date.setMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes):

```js
var dat = '2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z'; //obj.starttime; 
let dt = new Date(dat);
console.log('getMinutes(): '  +  dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'UTC', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' })   );

// to Add minutes:
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 10);
console.log('getMinutes(): '  +  dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'UTC', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' })   );
```